# Cannot display message box on dev server in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, messagebox

I have a code block that is supposed to display a windows style message box to the user in my asp.net application.

The user performs an action on an asp.net page, that page then processes data on another aspx page. The second aspx page is where the message box code is to be displayed.

The box is displayed on my local machine, and another developers local machine. But the dev server does not display it. Nothing in the error log either.

**Code**

```
Page1.aspx

                Dim strString As String = SysUtility.CheckRecord(Session("UserID"), sPageType)
                If Mid(strString, 1, 6) = "ERROR:" Then MsgBox(strString, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)


Page2.aspx
function CheckRecord(strPage)
    .....
    .... database check to see if record is valid
    ....
    .... if invalid, return "Error: Invalid record"
    ....

end function
```

How can I resolve this issue (need to display the message box when app is migrated to the dev server)

Comment: how are you presenting the message box? we need code.

Comment: Are you trying to display a windows forms message box?

Comment: @asawyer... yes. An alert box or a msgbox;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MsgBox is for WinForms. In ASP.NET, you have the Javascript `alert` and `confirm` dialogs, and the jQuery UI Dialog. You can also use the `ModalPopupExtender` included in the AJAX Toolkit. There are other solutions too, but those are the most common.

The simplest solution would be to show an alert, and you can do that like this:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "ShowMessageScript", "alert('Hello World!');", true);
```

Comment: No message box display when using your syntax. No error messages either

Comment: It depends on where you put the code. Try putting it in a button click event in the code-behind.

Comment: No button click event available, or for that matter, any click event

Comment: When is your code running, and are you using AJAX or anything?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by when is my code running (it's a user perform action on an href, which sends the information to another page, then to another page, then to the Page1.aspx detailed above); No ajax is used, though javascript is used;

Comment: If the alert should be displayed on the second page, but the second page redirects back to the first page, there won't be an opportunity to show an alert.

Comment: I can live with the alert being on the either page (just to get this app completed and out the door)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot execute win 32 api calls on a client computer from code running in your IIS web server!

Setup a system where alert style messages are rendered down to the page in an onload javascript alert type message, or maybe a jquery growl style plugin.

Comment: It wasn't me that downvoted you, but I think your answer could be improved upon.

Comment: @James sure, but there are already answers that contain anything I would have edited in that where added after mine so...

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to use MsgBox as that is a windows forms thing. There are several ways you could display a similar sort of thing in asp.net.

If it's just for tracing purposes (you mention "dev server") then a simple;

```
Response.write("Computer says no");
```

would work. If you need it to be nice and styled for the user, you could put a protected string in your code behind...

```
protected string _errorMessage = "";
```

assign whatever value you want to it on your page load, then a nugget on the page itself;

```
<%= _errorMessage %>
```

you could place wherever you want, and use a combination of html elements and a placeholder to mark it up however you like.

The final alternative would be to squirt some javascript on to your page which uses the "alert" method, which would look almost exactly like a windows forms popup, but generally they are not good practice in web design.

Comment: I am ok with the javascript on my page, but how would I call it from Page1.aspx?

Comment: You can't call client side stuff from the server directly, you'd need to squirt the call into the page. See James Johnsons response on how to do that programatically (although remember that JS is interpreted so your call would need to be squirted in below your function definition). Alternatively, you could put JS in using the nugget method i described.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done in the way that you want it to be done. If you plan to execute something like `MsgBox` or `MessageBox.Show` in your server's code behind you will be out of luck. The reason you cannot do this is because a modal popup box would appear on the server and would block the process until someone somewhere on that server clicks OK or Cancel, or whatever button. What you need is to do this on the client side by calling javascript `alert()` function.